# Permutations with GUI in python

Tags: python, tkinter

## Hello everyone!

I have been working with simple permutations for numbers what I type. But I wanted something better so I started to make a GUI app on it, but I got stuck.

Goals from this program:

- Get permutations from numbers entered
- Show them in Label
- Make it clear to read

first two I have done that's *sort of easy* but I got stuck on the last thing...

 Any help is appreciated

My current Code:

```py
from itertools import permutations
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("tester")

Label1 = tk.Label(root)
Label1.pack()


entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()


my_list2 = []


def Calculate2(event=None):
    my_list2.clear()
    numbers2 = entry2.get()
    numbers = " ".join(numbers2)
    num = f"{numbers}".split()
    perm = permutations(num)

    for i in list(perm): 
        my_list2.append(str(i))
    print(*my_list2)
    Label1.config(text=", ".join(my_list2))

button_calculate2 = tk.Button(text="Calculate Permutations", command=Calculate2)
button_calculate2.pack()

root.bind('<Return>', Calculate2)

root.mainloop()
```

it prints it like this:

[image: this is the result, I want make it cleaner]

I want to make it cleaner...

To define Cleaner, I want something like this:

[image: This is what I want]

simply I want to generate all possible numbers from numbers what I entered and display them like the image above ^^^

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Kos my problem is that I want to make it cleaner the result in the Label, but when I try I do not succeed...

Comment: How do you define "cleaner"? Instead of using adjectives, show us exactly what you want to see.

Comment: check my edit, I think its enough to understand what I mean by cleaner

Comment: Try. `my_list2.append(", ".join(i))` to remove the `("...")`

Comment: @stovfl it makes it cleaner but it prints only some numbers... so it's not usable...

Comment: @stovfl done it you can check what i meant.

Comment: @stovfl everything is the same as you told me, and can you please move this to chat so we can avoid extended comments (something?)...?

Comment: If you don't want to show your attempt, I can't help any more.

Comment: @BryanOakley you can check my edit what I meant by cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
from itertools import permutations
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("tester")

Label1 = tk.Label(root)
Label1.pack()


entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()


my_list2 = []


def Calculate2(event=None):
    my_list2.clear()
    numbers2 = entry2.get()
    numbers = " ".join(numbers2)
    num = f"{numbers}".split()
    perm = permutations(num)
    for i in list(perm):
        result = ', '.join(map(str,i))
        my_list2.append(result)
    Label1.config(text=" | ".join(my_list2)+f" | amount: {len(my_list2)}")

button_calculate2 = tk.Button(text="Calculate Permutations", command=Calculate2)
button_calculate2.pack()

root.bind('<Return>', Calculate2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you! this is what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what do you want. But should help you.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("tester")

Label1 = tk.Label(root)
Label1.pack()
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()
my_list2 = []

def Calculate2():
    num1=[]
    num2=""
    my_list2.clear()
    numbers2 = entry2.get()
    for n in numbers2:
        num1.append(n)
    for i in reversed(range(len(num1))):
        num2+=num1[i]

    print(*my_list2)
    Label1.config(text=numbers2+","+num2)

button_calculate2 = tk.Button(text="Calculate Permutations", 
command=Calculate2)
button_calculate2.pack()
def calc(event):
    Calculate2()

root.bind('<Return>', calc)
root.mainloop()
```

Good luck...
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it is, but a slight issue with this... when I put 3 digit number it doesn't work because it doesn't who every possible number, and you reverted the number only, so it's not what I want, I want to generate all possible numbers from numbers I enter...

Comment: This work with any digits numbers(2 or 3 or 4 ......).  See the picture

Comment: but that's not what I wanted, sorry... you're just reverting a number, but I want to print the possible numbers from numbers I enter. anyways thanks.